# Extending class with generic types AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>

Tags: java

The class signature: `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`

I have multible instances of classes which extend `AsyncTask` and in each classes `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute(Result)` I execute the same functions. I want to write something like `BaseAsyncTask <Params, Progress, Result>` which would already include the functions in `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute(Result)`.

Is this possible?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.  Is myMethod1() defined in ClassName?  If so, does it use any of the three generic types?  Go ahead and use the actual method names.  From the title it looks like you're talking about the AsyncTask in the Android API.

Comment: I updated my question. `onPreExecute()` (myMethod1) and `onPostExecute(Result)` are defined in `AsyncTask` (ClassName) and I override them to do functions before and after `doInBackground(Params... params)` [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: _"Is this possible?"_ What have you tried? Are you running into problems?

Comment: When I use the `MyBaseAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>` and want to extend class with `MyBaseAsyncTask` I get an error: `The type MyBaseAsyncTask is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, String, ArrayList<Topic>>`. Also I have tried `MyBaseAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<T extends Object, T extends Object, T extends Object>` but on that point I got syntax error (I don't remember exactly what the error said. I cant think of any other ways to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

If you want MyBaseAsynTask to use generics, you'll have to define it like this:

```
class MyBaseAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

Then you can only use those generic types in any method implementations in MyBaseAsyncTask